# How to pass parameters to "Report summary" component in community page

Tags: reporting, community, community-builder, joined-reports, report-chart

I have to use reports in community with template Napili.
When i use 'Report summary' component in 'Report detail' template reports work well instead of 'Report chart' component in other pages.

Later I tried to pass parameter to report through URL '(like "fv0=" etc.)' but it hasn't worked :( It's very unconfortable because i need to make external URL for report in community with parameters.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the ID straight into the field like this:

[image]